# Completely regular Hausdorff does not imply local compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

We know that every locally compact [Hausdorff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space) is completely regular. Is the converse also true?

Comment: I think that any infinite-dimensional Banach space should provide a counterexample. Such spaces are not locally compact.

Answer (score 6):

$$\mathbb{Q}\mbox{}\mbox{}\mbox{}\mbox{}\mbox{}\mbox{}$$

Comment: Sorry, I added $\mathbb{Q}$ to my answer without seeing your response.

Comment: Another post from this site concerned with $\mathbb Q$ not being locally compact: [Rationals are not locally compact and compactness](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45649/rationals-are-not-locally-compact-and-compactness)

Answer (score 4):

No. A good place to look for examples is among metric spaces (metric spaces are completely regular, even normal). Here are some metric space examples.

- $X = [(0,1) \times (0,1)]  \cup \{p\}$ where $p = \langle 0,0 \rangle$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the standard Euclidean topology. $X$ is not locally compact. The point $p$ has no compact neighbourhoods (i.e. there are no compact sets $K$ with $p \in U \subset K$ for some open set $U$).
- $X = \mathbb{Q}$, again in the Euclidean topology. This time every compact set <strike>is finite, and so in particular,</strike> has empty interior.
- As @AGM points out in the comments, infinite-dimensional Banach spaces are another source of metric space counter-examples.

Comment: A compact set in $\Bbb Q$ is not necessarily finite. Take $\left(\frac1n\right)_n\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the comment. Fixed.

Comment: I like that you erased the mistake yet left it visible.